# Dynamically casting to IEnumerable<T> or T

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a class that accepts `T` and has a method that takes an `HttpResponseMessage` and modifies the content in the response.

```
public class MyClass<T> {

    HttpResponseMessage Modify(HttpResponseMessage response) {
        T content;
        if(response.TryGetContentValue(out content)) {
            DoSomethingWithContent(content);
        }
        return response;
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithContent(T content) {}

    public void DoSomethingWithContent(IEnumerable<T> content) {}
}
```

Used like this...

This works as long as the response content value is of type `T`,  **but sometimes it's `IEnumerable<T>`, and when that's the case `TryGetContentValue()` will return false since `T` is not `IEnumerable<T>`**. So I created an overload for `DoSomethingWithContent` but I'm struggling to figure out an efficient way to dynamically cast or declare `content` to the proper type so the correct overload is called.

**Answer**

I went with `recursive`s answer but I wanted to post the complete method for reference:

```
public class MyClass<T> {

    HttpResponseMessage Modify(HttpResponseMessage response) {
        object content;
        if(response.TryGetContentValue(out content)) {
            if(content is IEnumerable<T>)
                DoSomethingWithContent((IEnumerable<T>)content);
            else
                DoSomethingWithContent((T)content);
        }
        return response;
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithContent(T content) {}

    public void DoSomethingWithContent(IEnumerable<T> content) {}
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for this?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I don't think that's quite what is going on here.

Comment: Well, it was worth a try.

Comment: Generally when I ask this kind of question to myself, it is because I've not designed things as well as I could. It may be worth seeing if you can refactor your code to not need any sort of runtime tests.

Comment: @CoryNelson I agree with you - got to get it working first, then on to refactoring :)

Comment: Just a thought: how performance-critical is this? Could you just require IEnumerable no matter what and avoid the entire issue?

Comment: I really generalized with this question, and maybe that is some of the confusion. This class is actually used to enrich responses when the response content contains `T`. But I also wanted it to be able to enrich the response when it contains `IEnumerable<T>` as well. And both are likely.

Comment: If you have your own answer, you should post it as an answer (there may be a time delay before you can do so); the **question** text should only contain the **question**

Comment: recursives answer is the answer, I just wanted to show the class in whole with the changes - it could help someone out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `is` to determine which case to use.

```
if (content is IEnumerable<T>)
    DoSomethingWithContent((IEnumerable<T>)content);
else
    DoSomethingWithContent(content);
```

If you're feeling sassy, you could just use the runtime binder by casting to dynamic, but that's not recommended.

```
DoSomethingWithContent((dynamic)content);
```

Comment: but what about the declaration of content. Right now i have `T content` before I try to get the content value

Comment: but `DoSomethingWithContent` accepts `T` or `IEnumerable<T>`. Declaring content as object results in `Cannot resolve method..., candidates are...`

Comment: If you want to declare `object content`, then you can do the same test and cast with `T` as I showed for `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

The `IEnumerable<out T>` is **covariant**, so if you just...

```
var enumerable = content as IEnumerable<T>;
if (enumerable == null)
    DoSomethingWithContent(content);
else
    DoSomethingWithContent(enumerable);
```

...it will still call `DoSomethingWithContent(IEnumerable<T> content)` even if the actual run-time type of `content` is `IEnumerable<C>`, where `C` inherits `T`.

---

This doesn't address why you are trying "fit" `IEnumerable<T>` in `T` in the first place?

Comment: The question is not about `IEnumerable<T>` vs `IEnumerable<C>`.  It's about `IEnumerable<T>` vs `T`.

Comment: @recursive Which is what `as` tests at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah there is circularity problem with your design. If `MyClass<T>` is initialized as for example `MyClass<List<string>>` then `T = List<string>` so the overloaded definition won't actually get invoked. What you actually need to do is use only a single method *but* have a clause to test if `T` implements `IEnumerable<T>`. You can do this like;

```
if (content is IEnumerable<T>)
```

I'm not entirely sure that will work though because you may even have to specify the type the IEnumberable uses. If that's the case then check if it implements the non-generic IEnumberable because all collections that implement the generic version also implement the non-generic version.

Comment: Actually, I really like this idea. Going to think about this one.

Answer (score 1):

This work out?

```
HttpResponseMessage Modify(HttpResponseMessage response) {
        T content;
        if(response.TryGetContentValue<T>(out content)) {
            DoSomethingWithContent(content);
        }
        else 
        {
           IEnumerable<T> content;
           if(response.TryGetContentValue<IEnumerable<T>>(out content)) {
            DoSomethingWithContent(content);
           }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `DoSomething` is the same thing for `IEnumerable<T>` and `T` (eg., that one delegates to the other) - I think it'd make more sense to just always use an `IEnumerable<T>` - after all, a `T` is just an `IEnumerable<T>` with 1 value.

Of course, that sidesteps the problem that `TryGetContentValue` will only ever give you back a `T` - not an `IEnumerable<T>`. You could handle that by first trying `T` and then fall back to `IEnumerable<T>`. I think pulling it out as an object and handling the cast yourself may work as well.

So - I think you'll end up with something like:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    HttpResponseMessage Modify(HttpResponseMessage response) {
        IEnumerable<T> content = this.GetContent(response);
        DoSomethingWithContent(content);
        return response;
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> GetContent(HttpResponseMessage response) {
        object content;
        if (!response.TryGetContentValue(out content)) return new T[] { };
        if (content is T) return new T[] { (T)content };
        return content as IEnumerable<T> ?? new T[] { };
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithContent(IEnumerable<T> content) {
        foreach (var t in content) {
          // blah, blah
        }
    }
}
```

If `DoSomethingWithContent(T)` and `DoSomethingWithContent(IEnumerable<T>)` are in fact different - then you'd basically follow the same pattern as `GetContent` to make the branching decision.

Comment: Very elegant, I like this a lot. Thank you Mark